# Visual Studio - A faster way to publish?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have an ASP.NET application in VS2008 that is growing larger and am developing and testing on IIS7, not Cassini/IIS dev, so when I make changes, I publish, run and test.

The publish is taking longer and longer, since there are more and more builds for different projects within the solution.  If I want to make simple changes to say an aspx file, instead of publishing, I just modify the published version to avoid the cost of the publish which is a pain.

Is there a better/faster way?  Is there something out there that talks about best practices/efficient publish/run/test techniques for VS2008?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I just created a virtual site in my IIS running on port 1337 (Ye, I'm a geek, but I find that funny :P ), which points to the root of my project. I keep a browser open on localhost:1337, press F6 in VS and then F5 in my browser - no need to publish :)

Works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks- I'll give that a try - what if you have url rewrites and/or code that is url dependent?

Comment: Yeah, that could be a problem - But imho, if your code doesn't run on localhost, it's either bad code or some 3rd party licensed widget. If it's the latter, you're out of luck I guess :( . Correct me if I misunderstood your question :)

Comment: Come to think of it, my rewrites are taken care of by IIS7, so I think I should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

simply try to  separate data, auto generated files and business layers in different projects, so you won't need to build the all solution, just parts of that. 
Also make a clone locally, make changes and publish online using repository tools, like GIT or SVN.

Comment: GIT + Visual Studio == massive, massive pain. SVN okay though. :)

Comment: Contrary, we switched from SVN to GIT as it was fast (using console) and very flexible. I guess it depends on the specific projects.