# Is there a faster way to publish website compared to uploading it using MS Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a big site and it takes ages to publish it using VS.

How can I make this process faster?

Please suggest.

I have a shared hosting server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885133/publishing-an-asp-net-mvc2-site-with-web-deploy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321363/visual-studio-a-faster-way-to-publish

Comment: @JK, I had checked the last link that you send. It talks about Virtual Site and stuff. But is that possible if we have shared hosting? Also not sure how Virtual site needs to be setup.

Comment: why not try to publish to the local file system, zip the folder and deploy manually by uploading & copying it on your host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create a FTP folder from your "My Computer."  Then just drag and drop all you want.